# How do I adjust for foreign characters when working with javascript language files served by requireJS?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, internationalization, requirejs

I'm trying to build a template using `requireJS` and `jquery-mobile`. I'm pulling data from a offline/online source and grab text files via requireJS `i18n` plugin ([here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html).

All works well except for foreign characters.

My language files contain pretty much nothing. They look like this:

```
define({
    "tx_sel_choose_retailer":"Händler wählen",
    "tx_sel_delete":"Löschen"
});
```

Which is pulled in via requireJS.

**Question**:
How can I make characters like `äöü` show up like I need when using this bundle? Do I have to declare something in Javascript, because the characters are wrong once I pull them in for constuctring my elements (before putting them in the page).

Thanks for some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 things you need to handle:

- Claimed encoding
- Physical encoding

Claimed encoding is what http headers your server sends, I.E. the http header `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8` will claim that the file is in utf-8 encoding. You can also claim encoding in your html source with the meta tags but real http headers are preferred.

Then on the other side you have the actual physical encoding of the file, if you claim that the file is utf-8, but it is physically something else, you will not get expected results. You need to configure your text editor to save the file in the same encoding that you claim the file to be.

Comment: so if I end up generating the file on the server from my database table (I'm using Coldfusion), I would need to set the encoding when saving? No I'm curious... and starting to search. Thanks so far!

Comment: @frequent Yes, when saving the file you need to explicitly state that the file must be saved in utf-8. There could be more complications if the data was already screwed up in the database already, or your connection encoding isn't set properly etc. In coldfusion something like this: `<cffile action="write" charSet="UTF-8" 
 file="C:\something\something.js"
 output="data">`

Comment: Found it. Notepad++ default encoding = ANSI. Switched to UTF-8, now perfect. Thank you very much again!

Comment: @frequent note that in `Notepad++` you want to use `UTF-8 without BOM`, the `UTF-8` encoding in Notepad++ adds encodes the useless-for-utf8-bom character at the start of file.